# Meetings Disappearing from Outlook 2010 Public Calendar

Tags: windows-7, outlook-2010, public-folders, calendar

We are experiencing a frustrating issue with our Public Calendars in Outlook 2010.  Meetings that have been scheduled months in advance are missing, but will then reappear.

If user A logs in @ 9:30 and goes to the calendar, certain meetings will be missing.  15 Minutes later, when user B logs in, the meetings are there.  It is not tied to the actual user- I have seen this issue occur with the order of logging in reversed.

These are with meetings that were posted to the calender months ago, so it should not be an issue of an item being updated.  We have not upgraded our Exchange environment (still running on 2003), but this is a new machine, running Windows 7 Professional, on a domain, running office 2010.

Are there any quirks or settings that I am missing or not aware of?

Comment: Have you tried turning off cached mode in outlook, or viewing the calendar from webmail to see if it's a client side or server side issue?  Is it only this one client machine that has this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you determining that the items exist or not?  Are you looking at the scheduling assistant?  That depends on the free/busy information published by the Outlook client.  Different clients could be configured to publish different amounts of free/busy information.  Which would make an appointment scheduled out in the future either be visible or not.

See:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/867504
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996946(EXCHG.65).aspx